# minimum value of $E[Y - g(X)]^2$

Tags: self-study, distributions, prediction, random-variable, conditional-expectation

When is $E[Y - g(X)]^2$ at it's minimum value over possible transforms $g$?
I guess it's when $g(x) = E[Y|X]$. But i'm unable to prove it. Any ideas or hints how can i start the proof? (If i'm right about the answer)

Comment: Welcome to CV, Ju Bc. It looks like you are asking a `self-study` question. I would recommend editing your question (with the small "edit" link in lower left) to (1) include the `[self-study]` tag, and to (2) possibly incorporate some of the guidance on how to effectively ask a `self-study` question given in its [tag description](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: The problem (as well as answers) are incorrect, the criterion should be $E[(Y - g(X))^2|X]$. If the conditioning part is missing, one cannot conclude that the cross product term is 0.

Comment: Your comment is wrong @Zhangxiong. I will add more detail to my existing answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
[Y-g(X)]^2 &= [Y-\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]+\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]-g(X)]^2 \\
&= [Y-\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]]^2+[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]-g(X)]^2+2[Y-\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]][\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]-g(X)]
\end{align}$$
Now, by double expectation,
$$\mathbb{E}[Y-g(X)]^2 = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}\left\{[Y-g(X)]^2 \mid X\right\}]\text{.}$$
Looking at the third term of $\mathbb{E}[Y - g(X)]^2$ above, notice that $$\mathbb{E}\left\{Y-\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X] \mid X\right\}= \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X] - \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]\mid X]=\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X] - \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X] = 0$$
so thus, we end up with 
$$\mathbb{E}[Y - g(X)]^2 = \mathbb{E}[Y-\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]]^2+\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]-g(X)]^2\text{.}\tag{1}$$
Note that in $(1)$, the only term dependent on $g(X)$ on the right side is $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]-g(X)]^2$. Since this is the expectation of a squared quantity, we know that 
$$[\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]-g(X)]^2 \geq 0$$
which means that minimization happens when 
$$\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]-g(X) = 0$$
or $$g(X) = \mathbb{E}[Y \mid X]\text{.}$$

Answer (score 4):

Add and substract $E(Y|X)$ in your expression and condition to $X$ to prove the undebraced expression is equal to zero.
\begin{align*}
 & E(Y - g(X))^2 = \\
&E (Y- E(Y|X))^2 + 2\underbrace{E\left[(Y - E(Y|X) (E(Y|X) - g(X))\right]}_{=0} + E(E(Y|X) - g(X))^2  \\
&\geq E(Y- E(Y|X))^2
\end{align*}

To reply to the comments in the question here is why the underbraced expression is equal to zero.

$$E\left[(Y - E(Y|X) (E(Y|X) - g(X))\right] = E \{ E\left[(Y - E(Y|X) (E(Y|X) - g(X))|X\right] \} =  E \{(E(Y|X) - g(X)) \underbrace{E \left[(Y - E(Y|X) |X\right]}_{=0} \} = 0 $$
Where the term $E(E(Y|X) - g(X))$ goes out the conditional expectation to $X$ because it is a function of $X$.

Comment: How do you show that the middle term is zero?

Comment: @Zhanxiong It is already hinted that you have to condtiion to X. Because the second factor is a function of $X$ it comes out of the conditioning and the first factpr is is equal to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Since answers have already been provided, here is a short intro to conditional expectations as $L^2$ projections, i.e. for an alternative path to conditional expectations in which the question asked is taken more or less as definition.

Intuitively, taking the expected value of $Y$ conditioned on $X$ means averaging $Y$ over events which produce the outcomes of $X$. If we think of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$, $\sigma(X)$, as grouping events leading to the same outcomes of $X$, then we see that we want the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ to be a r.v. over $\sigma(x)$, closest in some sense to the original $Y$.

Therefore, if we work in $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$, with $\mathcal{A}$ a $\sigma$-algebra over $\Omega$, then the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ has a natural definition as the $L^2$ projection of Y onto $L^2$ of $\sigma(X)$ since $L^2(\Omega, \sigma(X), P)$ is a closed subspace of $L^2(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y|X] = \operatorname{argmin}_g \mathbb{E}[(Y-g(X))^2]$$

over all Borel $g$ such that $g(X) \in L^2$ (recall that $Z$ is measurable wrt. $\sigma(X)$ iff there is some Borel $g$ such that $Z=g(X)$)

The case $L^1$ is not so straightforward because we lack the Hilbert space structure, see e.g. "Jacod, Protter: Probability essentials", Chapter 23.

Conditional expectations can be taken over any sub $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{A}$. For a nice introduction starting from conditioning on $\sigma$-algebras and with pictures and intuition, see ["Conditional Expectations without tears"](https://pizzaseminar.speicherleck.de/skript4/0x-conditional-expectation/ConditionalExpectation.pdf).

Comment: Nice intro and reference!